# Passing parameter through h:link in jsf page

Tags: jsf-2

I am trying to pass the parameter on the click of the link. The values of the link and the parameter being passed are different.

```
<h:link outcome="/person" value="#{users.userId}" >

                            <f:param name="number" value="123abc"/>
                            </h:link>
```

User id : [xyz987](http://abc.com)

When the user clicks on the link, value "**123abc**" should be passed as parameter, but in this case **xyz987** is being passed

What I am doing wrong here. I want to pass 123abc not xyz987.

Comment: Where is the `xyz987` value supposed to be coming from? Is it setup somewhere? It didn't generate itself no?

Comment: it is coming from the bean ... users.userid